# Android export signed apk issues

Tags: android

I have project that consists of actually this project and 2 library projects. I am trying to sign this apk (using Eclipse). Before it has worked! But now I cannot build the WORKING apk! Every time it has different size and every time different functions are not working! It makes me crazy!
It works with the debug key, but with real key the app doesn't work.
Is there any way to make the app working?

Comment: can you provide some details?

Comment: What details should I provide? Debug key - works. Real - has worked, now - doesn't work.

Comment: Is [Proguard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) enabled for your project? If so, there's probably a class or some data that is being obfuscated. (The app behavior may be different every time you build in this case.)

Comment: I have the same issue, export signed APK always gives varying file sizes and most times not installable/crash on launch etc

Comment: make sure that your ADT is updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated ADT. Seems works now.